# How to make a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter register at an endpoint other than /login?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, servlet-filters

I've been following a [tutorial to implementing JWT authentication in Spring Boot](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) but am trying to adapt it to a case where I have two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes, one for my API (`/api/**` endpoints) and one for my web front-end (all other endpoints).  In the tutorial, a `JWTAuthenticationFilter` is created as a subclass of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and added to the chain.  According to the author, this filter will automatically register itself with the "`/login`" endpoint, but I want it to point somewhere different, such as "`/api/login`" because I'm using this authentication method for my API only.

Here's the security configuration code for both the API and front-end (with some abbrevation):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultipleSecurityConfigurations {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class APISecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    public static class FrontEndSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll() 
                    .mvcMatchers("/home").authenticated() 
                    .anyRequest().denyAll() 
                    ;
        }

    }

}
```

The question is: **how can I define an endpoint such as "`/api/login`" as the endpoint for my custom `JWTAuthenticationFilter`?**

Or, do I need to change the filter to *not* be a subclass of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and if so, how would I configure that?

EDIT: Something I've tried:

I guessed that the `/api/login` endpoint needed to be `.permitAll()` and I tried using `formLogin().loginProcessingUrl()`, even though it's not really a form login - it's a JSON login.  This doesn't work.  When i POST to `/api/login` I end up getting redirected to the HTML login form as if I were not logged in.  Moreover, my Spring boot app throws a weird exception:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
```

The configuration I'm trying now:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login").and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }
```

Comment: i dont see any issue with your configuration. Can you please share more exception trace and JWTAuthenticationFilter,JWTAuthorizationFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `JWTAuthenticationFilter` is a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, you could change the login endpoint directly on the filter instance:

```
JWTAuthenticationFilter customFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
customFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");

http.addFilter(customFilter);
```

This configures `JWTAuthenticationFilter` to attempt to authenticate POST requests to `/api/login`.

Comment: This was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish also to change the default POST to another method (e.g. GET), you can set the RequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher instead. For instance:

```
customFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login", "GET"));
```